# How to select xpath only if a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

My HTML looks like this:

```
div class = 'a-row a-spacing-small'
div class = 'a-row'
```

(These are in the same level, I mean second div is not a child of the first div) (both of them are same level parents)

I wanna select `href` from the inner levels of the first `div` where `class = 'a-row a-spacing-small'` only if something in the inner levels of the second div where `class = 'a-row'` satisfies a condition.

How can I do this?

Any ideas

Comment: Can you share more detailed `HTML`? What is this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so for your xpath, you want to start with the element you can identify easily or the root, in this case, the first `div` where class is `'a-row a-spacing-small'`:

`//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']`

next would be to identify how your element relates to this root element, so in this case, you want an `href` which would be in an `a` and that should be inside the `div` we identified..but you're not sure if it's a direct child..so you use `//`:

`//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

but then you only want this element, if the `div` next to it satisfies a condition..so we should put something at the start of the xpath before the xpath we've already created...

`//<somexpath>/div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

but what xpath? what we know is we're making the second `div` the root, since it has the condition we want...

`//div[@class='a-row']`

so how does the first `div` relate to our new root? it is a `preceding-sibling` because it is before the new root and it is on the same level..

`//div[@class='a-row']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

now whatever the condition is, we need to include it in the root...

`//div[@class='a-row' and <condition>]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

examples:

if the condition is that the div should have an `a` with the text "conditional link": 
`//div[@class='a-row' and .//a[text()='conditional link']]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

if the condition is that the div should have a disabled attribute:
`//div[@class='a-row' and @disabled]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

how about no disabled attribute?
`//div[@class='a-row' and not(@disabled)]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a/@href`

play with it...

Comment: of course you should also identify which `href` you're after..like is it in an `a` that has text "this link"? in that case: `//div[@class='a-row' and not(@disabled)]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small']//a[text()='this link']/@href`

Comment: Thank you so much! Excited to implement this =)

Comment: hello from future, this is still useful till now 2021